# Tell a friend in django

Tags: python, django, email, contacts, social-networking

I am looking for a generic Tell a Friend application in django which will allow my website users to invite and tell about website features to one's mail or social networking friends by sending invitation email to join the website....

Any suggestion will help...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't Django, but you might consider a remotely-hosted application like [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/).

Otherwise, you could make use of [this code](http://natebeacham.com/blog/nate-beacham/29/), and add parameters (such as name and email address) into the URL where possible / necessary. In any case, I'm not aware of a Django-specific solution that integrates with the CMS out of the box - you might have to do it yourself, at least partly.

Comment: Thanks, however what I am looking is not a share but tell a friend. Through which will allow us to send an invitation email to the user's friends describing the website features.

Comment: Ah ok - in any case, the reason I suggested this is that with most social applications (all included in ShareThis), the user can type a message with the `like` or `recommend` or whatever (ShareThis allows you to send email to friends as well) - I'm not sure you can target specific friends on Facebook then, however

Answer (score 2):

There's a reusable app at github called [django-tellafriend](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-tellafriend).

Haven't used it myself. In the essence however it shouldn't be to hard to roll your own app for this if you have special requirements. Basically you need a form and send out an email if it's valid. If you want to keep track of the you can store the information using a simple model.

Connecting to social networks might be a little trickier, but there are also a few django apps for this like [django-facebook](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook) and [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth).